# view city names on the map

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to view the names of the cities on a **d3.js v5** map
I tried some solutions so I am able to "just simply view the names of the cities " without the need of tooltip but I'm getting the following error in React *"You can't update unmounted component"*.

Below my current code, which is in a class based component, I tried to use hooks to no avail, all this concepts are new to me.

```
   // ... imports 

class MapPathHolder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          algyData: null,
          toCity: "Algiers",
        };
    }

    navigateToCity = () => {
       this.props.history.push("/ToCityProducts");
    };
    
    componentWillMount() {
       d3.json("algy.json").then((algyData) => {
          this.setState({
            algyData,
          });
        });
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
    const { width, height } = this.props;

    const dz = this.state.algyData;
    
    const svg = d3.select(this.refs.anchor);

    var projection = d3
      .geoEquirectangular()
      // .parallels([29.5, 45.5])
      .scale(1900.347057471)
      .center([3, 40]) 
      .translate([width / 1.4, height / 9]); 
    const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
    const g = svg.append("g");

     g.append("g")
      .attr("fill", "#4b4b4b")
      .attr("cursor", "pointer")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(
        topojson.feature(dz, dz.objects.collection).features
        )
      .join("path")
      .attr("stroke", "#A8846A")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", (d) => {
        this.props.postCity(d.properties.name);
        this.navigateToCity();
      })
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", "orange");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", "#4b4b4b");
      })
      .append("title")
      .text((d) => d.properties.name);

      g.append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr(
        "d",
        path(topojson.mesh(dz, dz.objects.collection, (a, b) => a !== b))
      );
     // error occurs  after adding this line 
     g.append("title").text((d) => d.properties.name);
    }

    render() {
        const { algyData, toCity } = this.state;

        if (!algyData) {
          return null;
        }

        return <g ref="anchor" />;
    }
 }

  // ... mapState/DispatchToProps()

 export default withRouter(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MapPathHolder));
```

Comment: When are you getting the error?

Comment: Don't you need to use `componentDidMount()` instead of will mount?

Comment: just updated the code ,  and changed to DidMount()
I followed an old example

Comment: Please try to turn your code into a runnable [mre], it will help us debug